# How to get Vertica copy from stdin response in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, stdin, vertica

I'm using Vertica Database 07.01.0100 and node.js v0.10.32. I'm using the [vertica nodejs module by vanberger](https://github.com/wvanbergen/node-vertica). I want to send a copy from stdin command, and that is working using this example: https://gist.github.com/soldair/5168249. Here's my code:

```
        var loadStreamQuery = "COPY \""+input('table-name')+"\" FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' skip 1 direct;"
        var stream = through();
        connection.copy(loadStreamQuery,function(transfer, success, fail){
            stream.on('data',function(data){
                log.info("loaddata: on data =>",data);
                transfer(data);
            });

            stream.on('end',function(data){
                log.info("loaddata: on end =>", data);
                if(data) {
                    transfer(data);                     
                }
                success();
                callback(null,{'result':{'status':'200','result':"Data was loaded successfully into Vertica"}});
            });
            stream.on('error',function(err){
                fail();
                log.error("loaddata: on error =>",err);
                connection.disconnect();
            });
            stream.write(new Buffer(file));
            stream.end();
        }
        );
```

But, if the data file has more columns than the target table, it doesn't say so. It just happily runs, copying nothing and then ends. When I look at the table, nothing has been loaded. If I do the same thing in dbvisualizer, it tells me that 0 rows were affected.

I would like to examine the status of the command, but I don't know how. Is there some other event that I need to listen for? Do I need to save the result of copy to a variable and listen there, like I do with query calls? I'm a nodejs noob, so if the answer is obvious, just let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think it is a `node.js` thing as much as it is a `Vertica` thing.

You need to look for rejected rows.  You can find some good examples in the docs [here](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/SavingLoadRejections.htm).

If you want to actually see the rows that reject, you can do this by using a `COPY` statement clause like `REJECTED DATA AS table "loader_rejects"`. Alternatively you can send it to a file on the cluster.  I'm not aware of a way to get rejected rows to a local file using STDIN.

If you don't care at all about the actual data, and just want to know how many rows loaded and rejected... you can use [`GET_NUM_REJECTED_ROWS()`](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/GET_NUM_REJECTED_ROWS.htm) and [`GET_NUM_ACCEPTED_ROWS()`](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/GET_NUM_ACCEPTED_ROWS.htm).  I think `COPY` will actually also return a result set with just the count of loaded rows, at least that is what I've noticed in the past.

So I guess as an example, if you want to see how many rows were accepted and rejected, you could do:

```
connection.query "SELECT GET_NUM_REJECTED_ROWS() AS REJECTED_ROWS, GET_NUMBER_ACCEPTED_ROWS() AS ACCEPTED_ROWS", (err, resultset) -> log.info( err, resultset.fields, resultset.rows, resultset.status )
```